# Pandas : fill NaN with the closest value, according to a category column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, missing-data

Let's take a sample dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2022-10-01","2022-10-02","2022-10-03","2022-10-04","2022-10-05","2022-10-06","2022-10-01","2022-10-02","2022-10-03","2022-10-04","2022-10-05","2022-10-06"],
                   "Animal" :["Cat","Cat","Cat","Cat","Cat","Cat","Dog","Dog","Dog","Dog","Dog","Dog"],
                   "Quantity":[np.nan,4,3,5,1,np.nan,6,5,np.nan,np.nan,2,1]})

          Date Animal  Quantity
0   2022-10-01    Cat       NaN
1   2022-10-02    Cat       4.0
2   2022-10-03    Cat       3.0
3   2022-10-04    Cat       5.0
4   2022-10-05    Cat       1.0
5   2022-10-06    Cat       NaN
6   2022-10-01    Dog       6.0
7   2022-10-02    Dog       5.0
8   2022-10-03    Dog       NaN
9   2022-10-04    Dog       NaN
10  2022-10-05    Dog       2.0
11  2022-10-06    Dog       1.0
```

I would like to fill the NaN values in the column `Quantity` using the following method :

- Replace the NaN values with the closest value that is **before** the NaN value and which share the same value in `Animal` column
- If there is still some NaN values, replace the remaining NaN values with the closest value that is **after** the Nan value and which share the same value in `Animal` column

I thought to [Series.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) but I don't know how to deal with the `Animal` column. Would you please know an efficient way to reach the expected output ?

Expected output :

```
          Date Animal  Quantity
0   2022-10-01    Cat         4
1   2022-10-02    Cat         4
2   2022-10-03    Cat         3
3   2022-10-04    Cat         5
4   2022-10-05    Cat         1
5   2022-10-06    Cat         1
6   2022-10-01    Dog         6
7   2022-10-02    Dog         5
8   2022-10-03    Dog         5
9   2022-10-04    Dog         5
10  2022-10-05    Dog         2
11  2022-10-06    Dog         1
``
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ffill`/`bfill` per group:

```
df['Quantity'] = (df.groupby('Animal', group_keys=False)['Quantity']
                    .apply(lambda s: s.bfill().ffill())
                 )
```

Output:

```
          Date Animal  Quantity
0   2022-10-01    Cat       4.0
1   2022-10-02    Cat       4.0
2   2022-10-03    Cat       3.0
3   2022-10-04    Cat       5.0
4   2022-10-05    Cat       1.0
5   2022-10-06    Cat       1.0
6   2022-10-01    Dog       6.0
7   2022-10-02    Dog       5.0
8   2022-10-03    Dog       5.0
9   2022-10-04    Dog       5.0
10  2022-10-05    Dog       2.0
11  2022-10-06    Dog       1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition tp `@mozway` sol (as I cant edit it). I've absorved the column should be typecasted to `int`

```
df['Quantity'] = (df.groupby('Animal', group_keys=False)['Quantity']
                    .apply(lambda s: s.bfill().ffill())
                 )

df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity'].astype('int')
print(df)
```

output #

```
          Date Animal  Quantity
0   2022-10-01    Cat         4
1   2022-10-02    Cat         4
2   2022-10-03    Cat         3
3   2022-10-04    Cat         5
4   2022-10-05    Cat         1
5   2022-10-06    Cat         1
6   2022-10-01    Dog         6
7   2022-10-02    Dog         5
8   2022-10-03    Dog         2
9   2022-10-04    Dog         2
10  2022-10-05    Dog         2
11  2022-10-06    Dog         1
```